# Rails Modeling and Validating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, oop, tdd

I keep getting this error. 
1) Failure:
CustomerTest#test_customer_should_be_valid [C:/Users/Nick/sites/mech_crm/test/models/customer_test.rb:13]:
Failed assertion, no message given.

Previously, I had an error saying that my sales_person_id was not present. To try and fix that I changed @sales_person = SalesPerson.new to SalesPerson.create.

This fixed the sales_person_id error, but for the life of me, I cannot figure why I am getting the customer_should_be_valid.

If anyone has a bone they could throw me, I'd appreciate it and as I get better at this, I will try to return the favor in the future.

Thank you so much.

**from customer_test.rb**

require 'test_helper'

class CustomerTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

```
def setup 

    @sales_person = SalesPerson.create(sales_person_name: "nick", sales_person_email: "nick@example.com", sales_person_division: "HVAC", sales_person_location: "Nebraska", sales_person_phone_number: "402-515-6757")

    @customer = @sales_person.customers.build(customer_name: "S.T.A.R. Labs", customer_address: " 123 Allen Drive", customer_city: "Cental City", customer_state:"PA", customer_vertical_market: "Scientific Experiments", customer_phone_number: "515 555 4543", customer_description: "Performs Scientific experiments in the aid of super heroes.")
end

test "customer should be valid" do 
    assert @customer.valid?
end

test "sales person id should be present" do
    @customer.sales_person_id = nil
    assert_not @customer.valid?
end

test "customer name should be present" do 
    @customer.customer_name = " "
    assert_not @customer.valid?
end

test "customer name length should not be too short" do
    @customer.customer_name = "aaaa"
    assert_not @customer.valid?
end

test "customer name length should not be too long" do
    @customer.customer_name = "a" * 151
    assert_not @customer.valid?
end


test "customer address should not be too short" do
    @customer.customer_address = "aaaa"
    assert_not @customer.valid?

end

test "customer address should be present" do 
    @customer.customer_address = " "
    assert_not @customer.valid?
end

test "customer city should not be too short" do
    @customer.customer_city = "aaaa"
    assert_not @customer.valid?
end

test "customer city should be present" do
    @customer.customer_city = " "
    assert_not @customer.valid?
end

test "customer state should not be too short" do
    @customer.customer_state = "a"
    assert_not @customer.valid?
end

test "customer state should be present" do
    @customer.customer_state = " "
    assert_not @customer.valid?
end

test "customer vertical market should not be too short" do
    @customer.customer_vertical_market = "aaaa" 
    assert_not @customer.valid?
end

test "customer vertical market should be present" do
    @customer.customer_vertical_market = " "
    assert_not @customer.valid?
end

test "customer phone number should not be too short" do
    @customer.customer_phone_number = "aaaaaaaa"
    assert_not @customer.valid?
end

test "customer phone number should be present" do 
    @customer.customer_phone_number = " "
    assert_not @customer.valid?
end

test "customer description should not be too short" do
    @customer.customer_description = "a" * 25
    assert_not @customer.valid?
end

test "customer description should be present" do
    @customer.customer_description = " "
    assert_not @customer.valid?
end

test "customer name should be unique " do
    dup_customer = @customer.dup
    dup_customer.customer_name = @customer.customer_name.upcase
    @customer.save
    assert_not dup_customer.valid?
end
```

end

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :sales_person
validates :sales_person_id, presence: true
validates :customer_name, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5, maximum: 150}, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
validates :customer_address, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}
validates :customer_city, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}
validates :customer_state, presence: true, length: {minimum: 2}
validates :customer_vertical_market, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}
validates :customer_phone_number, presence: true, length: {minimum: 9}
validates :customer_description, presence: true, length: {minimum: 26}
```

This is what Bash displays when I add p @customers.errors:

## Running:

............#, @messages={}>
F......................

Finished in 0.203430s, 172.0492 runs/s, 211.3747 assertions/s.

1) Failure:
CustomerTest#test_customer_should_be_valid [C:/Users/Nick/sites/mech_crm/test/models/customer_test.rb:14]:
Failed assertion, no message given.

35 runs, 43 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

Comment: Could you add your code to the question in text form rather than adding the image? It makes it much easier for us to play around with your code and reproduce your issue.

Comment: posted code instead of pics. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Make sure you format it too, use the `{}` button in the text editor

Comment: Add `p @customer.errors` in the test method before the `assert` line to see why it wasn't validated.

Comment: `@customer.errors` won't be populated before `valid?` is called. Call `@customer.valid?`, then print the `errors` object, and you'll see what it's complaining about.